# Getting user cookies from apps script

Tags: cookies, google-apps-script, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Is there an alternative to this javascript:

```
document.cookie
```

which can be run inside apps script?

Context:
I'm using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol and is trying to collect __utmz cookie values from inside apps script functions to apply them to:

`UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect...............')` requests.

That __utmz cookie is being assigned at http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/.... page.

Comment: Yeah, well, it works. But actually I again asked a wrong question, it turns out you can't get cross domain cookie values. So I'm confused - how do I get Install source/medium/campaign from the store page...

Comment: Your link doesn't have an answer about accessing cookie cross domain. I need data from a cookie at chrome.google.com while my sidebar is at *.googleusercontent.com. I can only access cookies that are set at *.googleusercontent.com.

Comment: Do you think it is possible that they will add linker to ga code to allow google apps getting data?   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-1.com'] );

Comment: I understood what to do. Haven't done yet. But at least I know it - I have to send traffic to chrome.google.com through an intermediary page, where I first set my own cookie, and then after install read that cookie somehow through an image or iframe. If you can help with code samples for reading cookie from img I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cookies: If users click a link from domain A to domain B you should add the `_ga` parameter that you get from [`linkerParam`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#linkerparam) to the link. Then on domain B you should set [`allowLinker`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#configuring_a_site_to_accept_linker_parameters) to `true` for GA to read the value of the `_ga` parameter and use it to identify the user as being the same as on domain A.